# Laravel 8: attach() does not seem to be working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I want to add a new role for each user who has registered a new account. So at `RegisterController.php`, I added this:

```
protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);

        $role = Role::where('name', 'manual user')->first();

        $user->roles()->attach($role->id);

        return $user;
    }
```

And I have already the row named `manual user` at `roles` table:

[image]

But now the problem, whenever I try to register a new user, it does not attach `$role->id` to the pivot table `role_user` table !!

Note that I have added these relationships also:

`User.php`:

```
public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
    }
```

`Role.php`:

```
public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }
```

And the migration of `role_user` table goes like this:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('role_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('role_id');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

So what is going wrong here? How can I fix this issue ?

I would really appreciate any idea or suggestion from you guys...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are saying `return User::create([` while using `$user` variable for attaching. Change it to `$user = User::create([`

Comment: @POOYAA OOPS, you're goddamn right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are saying `return User::create([` at first line of method, while using $user variable for attaching. Change it to `$user = User::create([`